# Does older simulator download will download corresponding sdk changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

I wanted to know if I have Xcode 9 and download iOS 10.3 simulator does it download 10.3 sdk implementation to map to that particular simulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , if you download old simulator it will run your code (developed with the current sdk ) in old sdk of the simulator whatever it is